# Help with CakePHP: i can't bake

Tags: cakephp-1.3, relationship, has-many

i am new with cakephp and have a problem. I have created 2 tables in mysql
The relation i'm trying to create is 'category_products' has many 'products'.

```
CREATE TABLE category_products (  
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
  name varchar(30) NOT NULL  
) ENGINE=InnoDB;  

CREATE TABLE products (  
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
  name varchar(30) NOT NULL,  
  category_product_id int NOT NULL,  
  FOREIGN KEY (category_product_id) REFERENCES category_products(id)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

When i bake 'category_products' is all fine, but when i bake 'products' in console, i get this:

```
=============================================================   
Possible Models based on your current database:  
1. CategoryProduct  
2. Product  
Enter a number from the list above,type in the name of another model, or 'q' to exit    
[q] > 2  

Baking model class for Product...  
Creating file /opt/lampp/htdocs/caketest/app/models/product.php  
Wrote `/opt/lampp/htdocs/caketest/app/models/product.php`  
Product Model was baked.  
SimpleTest is not installed. Do you want to bake unit test files anyway? (y/n)   [y] > n  

**Error: Missing database table 'categories' for model 'Category'**

============================================================  
Cakephp **doesn't create the view** and when i open the **model** for product.php and i see this at then end.  

var $belongsTo = array(  
        'CategoryProduct' => array(  
            'className' => 'CategoryProduct',  
            'foreignKey' => 'category_product_id',  
            'conditions' => '',  
            'fields' => '',  
            'order' => ''  
        )  
    );  

var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(  
        'Category' => array(  
            'className' => 'Category',  
            'joinTable' => 'category_products',  
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',  
            'associationForeignKey' => 'category_id',  
            'unique' => true,  
            'conditions' => '',  
            'fields' => '',  
            'order' => '',  
            'limit' => '',  
            'offset' => '',  
            'finderQuery' => '',  
            'deleteQuery' => '',  
            'insertQuery' => ''  
        )  
    );
```

My question is what am i doing wrong??? apparently cakephp thinks i'm trying create a
relation HABTM. I'm using cakephp 1.3.7

please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how bake is designed to work. You're not doing anything wrong except that you have products in the database so it thinks that category_products is HABTM. If you want it to work correctly, you have a few options options:

1- Remove the products table before baking category_products and then add the relationship in to category_products manually.

2- Change the products table to something else during baking, then go back into the models and update the names and relationships to Product.

3- Ignore the error you are getting and remove the HABTM relationship from the model.

Happy coding!